# Injecting custom metrics and dimensions into Product object

Tags: google-analytics, shopify

I'm sorry in advance if this has already been posted, I did a search and haven't found anything similar.

I hope that someone has an answer to this, as I've been trying to figure out how to do this, but without any success.

The issue is that I need to inject (somehow) a custom metric into the Product details before it gets sent to be able to override a metric value on Google Analytics.

Edit: When viewing Product details on Shopify and having set Google Analytics on the backend of the shop, it sends pageview and detail action with product details. Before that point happends, I want to inject "metric1":0 to that addProduct event. In the picture below, you can see where I need to add it.

[console details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxac4.png)

```
ga("ec:addProduct", {
  id: "G175000BZ1TH6171", 
  name: "Black Mask with Activated Bamboo Charcoal", 
  category: "", 
  quantity: 1, 
  price: "5.36", 
  brand: "Development Store Tests", 
  variant: null, 
  currency: "USD",
  metric1: 0 })
```

so I need to add "metric1":0 after "currency" in that object. As far as I found out, Shopify embeds the Google Analytics library via its own manager so anything that I add to product.liquid is called after that which is a problem. Is there any way to do this?

Any kind of help would be useful. Thank you for replying!

Comment: Welcome at SO @Jadeferty. I like your kindness but 3 of 4 lines in your question are not on topic. Please be so kind and elobarate a little further what your cuurent problem is, provide some background. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you! I've edited the post. I hope it's easier to understand now.

Answer (score 0):

Shopify takes the template like product.liquid (plus sections & includes) and turns that into an HTML string that gets sent to the browser. So if you know what you are doing, there is nothing stopping you from injecting whatever you want into the product details. You are free as a bird to convert yin to yang and back before the output goes to the browser. Since no analytics operate at that stage, you are safe there. So do your magic.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm quite new to shopify themes and shopify analytics. I'm trying to figure how it works.